# itunes - mp4 files randomly divided between "Movies" and "Home Videos" in library

Tags: itunes, appletv, metadata

I'm using the most current version of iTunes on a PC, and streaming movies to an Apple TV (Gen4).  I've noticed that though all movies come from the same Windows folder, iTunes divides them up, placing some in "Movies" and some in "Home Videos".  Is there a way to organize that more intuitively so that all my true movies go into "Movies" and all my videorecordings of family go into "Home Videos"?

Comment: Have you followed the steps to correctly organize your library, according to [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204668)?

Answer (score 1):

If you like using the Terminal, [download](https://code.google.com/archive/p/mp4v2/downloads) and [compile](http://hunterford.me/compiling-mp4v2-on-mac-os-x/) mp4v2, then run a command like:

```
mp4tags -i "movie" <filename>
```

Make a backup first, but I use this all time, works great.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really pre-determine the category in which any given video file will end up in iTunes, without editing its metadata. This is indeed kind of annoying, and I also often have to hunt around to see where a video I've just imported has gone.

Luckily, once you find them, it's easy to move multiple files afterwards from Movies to Home Videos (and vice versa):

- Select the files you want to move
- Select Edit > Get Info (probably Ctrl-I, on a Windows machine)
- In the Options tab, select 'Movie' or 'Home Video' from the Media Kind dropdown